# Unable to install Pip for Pypy on Debian

Tags: debian, pip, pypy

I'm currently trying to use pypy but unfortunately unable to use pip the python package manager.

I added the following mirror to my source.list:

```
deb http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian jessie main
```

I installed then the pypy package using apt-get:

```
apt-get install pypy
```

Then I followed the steps given by the pypy documentation to install pip :

```
curl -O http://python-distribute.org/distribute_setup.py
curl -O https://raw.github.com/pypa/pip/master/contrib/get-pip.py
pypy distribute_setup.py
pypy get-pip.py
```

but i'm unable to find the pip executable for pypy.

The only trace of pip for pypy is this one :

```
root@computer:/usr/local/lib/pypy2.7/dist-packages# ll
total 24
drwxr-sr-x 6 root staff 4096 mars   1 19:29 distribute-0.6.49-py2.7.egg
-rw-r--r-- 1 root staff  215 févr. 26 03:43 easy-install.pth
drwxr-sr-x 7 root staff 4096 mars   1 18:07 pip
drwxr-sr-x 3 root staff 4096 févr. 26 03:44 pip-1.5.4.dist-info
-rw-r--r-- 1 root staff  144 févr. 26 03:43 setuptools-0.6c11-py2.7.egg-info
-rw-r--r-- 1 root staff   30 mars   1 19:29 setuptools.pth
```

But no pip executable.

Does somebody know a solution ?

EDIT:

In the pip file there is :

```
root@superswag:/usr/local/lib/pypy2.7/dist-packages/pip# ll
total 292
drwxr-sr-x 3 root staff 4096 févr. 26 03:44 backwardcompat 
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 6578 févr. 26 03:44 basecommand.py 
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 8162 févr. 26 03:44 baseparser.py 
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 9507 févr. 26 03:44 cmdoptions.py 
drwxr-sr-x 3 root staff 4096 févr. 26 03:44 commands 
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 22580 févr. 26 03:44 download.py 
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1086 févr. 26 03:44 exceptions.py 
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 40403 févr. 26 03:44 index.py 
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 9450 févr. 26 03:44 __init__.py 
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 6202 févr. 26 03:44 locations.py 
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 9455 févr. 26 03:44 log.py 
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 116 févr. 26 03:44 __main__.py 
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 2969 févr. 26 03:44 pep425tags.py 
drwxr-sr-x 2 root staff 4096 févr. 26 03:44 __pycache__ 
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 83557 févr. 26 03:44 req.py 
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 431 févr. 26 03:44 runner.py 
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 116 févr. 26 03:44 status_codes.py 
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 24172 févr. 26 03:44 util.py 
drwxr-sr-x 3 root staff 4096 févr. 26 03:44 vcs 
drwxr-sr-x 8 root staff 4096 févr. 26 03:44 _vendor 
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 20120 févr. 26 03:44 wheel.py
```

Comment: What is in this pip file? Where should the ppip file be?

Comment: This is probably related to the directories in the Debian package, which are different than the default ones.  In the default directory structure, "pip" is created alongside "pypy" the executable, which is in /opt/pypy-xxx/bin/.  You should really find out where it is for you; I suppose that any other pip-installed package will also put its binaries there (if any).  If you find where it is, please tell us so that we can document it :-)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Seems like pypy just installed the plain module. Nevertheless, you should be able to run pip using

```
pypy -m pip install <some package>
```

and alias this.