# pip-2.7 not found when using kivy buildozer

Tags: python, python-2.7, kivy

I am trying to use the kivy buildozer to package an application but I keep getting the following error:

```
/home/luke/.buildozer/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.7.egg-info already exists
# Install requirement sympy in virtualenv
# Run 'pip-2.7 install --download-cache=/home/luke/.buildozer/cache --target=/home/luke/.buildozer/applibs sympy'
# Cwd /home/luke/.buildozer
/bin/sh: 1: pip-2.7: not found
# Command failed: pip-2.7 install --download-cache=/home/luke/.buildozer/cache --target=/home/luke/.buildozer/applibs sympy
```

EDIT:
pip is installed, pip -V returns:

pip 1.5.4 from /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (python 2.7)

Comment: Have you installed pip for Python2.7 and is it accessible under the name `pip-2.7` from the same shell as the program you run which uses pip? Is this the whole information you got about the error?

Comment: Pip is installed python 2.7 but the name of the folder for it is just pip, not pip-2.7

Comment: Although I don't think that is the problem

Comment: Have a look maybe it helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22119136/unable-to-install-pip-for-pypy-on-debian/22121760#22121760

Answer (score 1):

On my machine pip-2.7 existed until I upgraded pip 1.0.2 to 1.5.4

Following that, I just had pip2.7 in /usr/local/bin.

A symlink to pip-2.7 from pip2.7 fixed it for me.

Answer (score 0):

Is your buildozer up to date? An issue with this was fixed fairly recently, and buildozer should now check multiple paths to find the right version of pip.

Comment: I am using version 0.10-dev which as far as I am aware is the most up to date version